# If $\mu(E)>0$ then $\exists E'\subseteq E$ such that $0<\mu(E')<\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Which measure $\mu$ have the property that for every measurable set $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$ there exist a measurable subset $E'\subseteq E$ such that $0<\mu(E')<\infty$?

At first I thought every measure satisfies this, but was not able to prove it. Then, I found that we can prove it for every $\sigma$-finite measure. But there are non-$\sigma$-finite measures which also satisfy this: for example the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Can we characterize all measures which satisfy this?

Comment: These are known as *semifinite measures*, and the property you stated is their definition.

Comment: Indeed, $\sigma$-finiteness implies semifiniteness, but not the converse.

Comment: As an example of a measure which does not satisfy this property, consider $\infty \cdot \nu$, where $\nu$ is counting measure.